# What do stars on weapons mean?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

At the bottom right you see there are some weapons with a star indicator. What does this mean?

[image: gungeon weapons]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That star indicates that these guns are "favourites" for quick swapping.

To set a favorite, hold down the weapon key so you get the gun selection wheel. It favorites your current gun and whatever gun you switch to.

Tapping the weapon button now toggles between the two. To change your favorites, do the same thing again.

If you don't want this feature, you can disable it in the options.